# Can't make REST API call from Android app to deployed PHP Server?

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

I am having trouble connecting to my Google Cloud PHP server that hosts a MySQL database. Here is my code for sending a notification to my PHP server.

NotificationInstanceService.java

```
public class NotificationInstanceService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationInstance";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //Getting registration token
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        //Displaying token on logcat
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        //You can implement this method to store the token on your server
        //Not required for current project
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        //Create the request body
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder().add("Token", token).build();
        //Know where to send the request to
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("<app server url>/register.php")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        //Create
        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

This seems to go through correctly and there doesn't seem to be any stack trace thrown. Then, when I deployed my PHP server, I have created the following files:

app.yaml:

```
application: <app server url>
service: default
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
version: alpha-001

handlers:

- url: /(.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.+\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: (.+\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: index.php
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: register.php
  login: admin
```

config.inc.php:

```
<?php 
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '<Secret>'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

// Change this to use the project and instance that you've created.
$host = '/cloudsql/<app server url>:us-central1:<database name>-app-php';
$type = 'socket';

/*
* First server
*/
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = $host;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = $type;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
// [END all]
```

php.ini:

```
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "php_uname, getmypid"
```

And lastly, `register.php` which is my php script located in the current directory of all these files:

register.php:

```
<?php

function dbg($data){
    file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/log.txt',$data.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND );
}

$conn = mysql_connect(':/cloudsql/<app server url>:us-central1:<database name>',
  'root', // username
  ''      // password
  );
        if (isset($conn) && isset($_POST["Token"])) {
                   $_uv_Token=$_POST["Token"];
                   echo $conn;
                   $q="INSERT INTO users (Token) VALUES ( '$_uv_Token') "
              ." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Token = '$_uv_Token';";

      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$q) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Inserted successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    dbg($q); /* where $q is the sql */
    dbg(print_r($result,true)); /* config */

      mysqli_close($conn);
        }
 ?>
```

I can't seem to find where I am going wrong with this. I cant seem to debug or find any error logs as to if I am connected to the wrong database, or if my REST call is simply getting intercepted somewhere for whatever reason. It seems that on the client side, in `NotificationInstanceService.java` the registration token is sent to the server, but then the server never actually stores the id or token in it. I am pretty sure I have all the URLs for my application server configured correctly. I tried to `$echo` all the responses and such I am getting but can't seem to find where to get these `$echo` statements. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might do to help debug ( other than checking the php errorlog ) is to write a small function that writes to a text file.

```
function dbg($data){
    file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/log.txt',$data.PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND );
}

/* then call it like: */
dbg($q); /* where $q is the sql */
dbg(print_r($cfg,true)); /* config */
```

Then use it though the php code to see what data you get at various stages - either by ftp download or browsing to that file location with a browser. Just an idea...

```
<?php

    function dbg($data){
        file_put_contents( __DIR__.'/log.txt', $data.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
    }

    /* !! assuming `config.inc.php` is available in `register.php` !! */
    dbg( print_r( $cfg, true ) );

    $conn = mysql_connect(':/cloudsql/<app server url>:us-central1:<database name>',
        'root',
        ''
    );

    dbg( 'errors: '.mysql_error( $conn ) );


    if ( $conn && isset( $_POST["Token"] ) ) {
        $_uv_Token=$_POST["Token"];

        dbg('POST-Token: '.$_uv_Token);

        $q="INSERT INTO users (Token) VALUES ( '$_uv_Token') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Token = '$_uv_Token';";
        dbg('sql: '.$q);


        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$q) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
        dbg('Query succeeded: '.$result);


        if ($result) {

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Inserted successfully created.";
            echo json_encode($response);

        } else {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }

        mysql_close( $conn );
    }
?>
```

Is `config.inc.php` included in `register.php`? I ask because you defined various settings in the config file but then go on, in `register.php` to hardocde them again.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and placed your code in my `register.php` file but I don't see a log.txt being created in my local directory. Any other things I could look at in how I can debug this?

Comment: the php errorlog ( if you have access to it ) might have errors displayed? One thing I noticed is `echo $conn;` ~ as `$conn` is an object this is liable to cause an error! Also, you are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli` functions

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestions but I still can't seem to get any output in log.txt. It's odd, it seems like I am able to deploy scripts like index.php, interact with them, etc, along with things like server_databases.php but I can't seem to get my own php script to work...